# NameError - uninitialized constant Sass::Engine:

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems, sinatra

I am getting  NameError - uninitialized constant Sass::Engine: when I run my sinatra app with sass gem.
installed ruby version 2.3.1 with rbenv and also installed sinatra, sass gem.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'slim'
require 'sass'  # required sass
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?

get '/styles.css' do
    scss :styles #does not generate styles.css, styles.scss file is in /views folder
end

get '/' do
    slim :home
end

get '/about' do
    @title = "All About This Website"
    slim :about
end

get '/contact' do
     slim :contact #, :layout => :special
end

not_found do
   slim :not_found
end

get '/fake_error' do
   status 500
   "There's nothing wrong, really :P"
end
```

**Full error:**

> NameError - uninitialized constant Sass::Engine:
>   /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.5/lib/tilt/sass.rb:13:in
>   `prepare'
>     /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.5/lib/tilt/template.rb:92:in`
>   initialize'
>     /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:862:in
>   `new'
>     /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:862:in`
>   block in compile_template'
>     /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.5/lib/tilt.rb:104:in
>   `block in fetch'
>     /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.5/lib/tilt.rb:103:in`
>   fetch'
>     /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.5/lib/tilt.rb:103:in
>   `fetch'
>     /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:841:in`
>   compile_template'
>     /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:822:in
>   `render'
>     /home/tasqyn/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sinatra-1.4.7/lib/sinatra/base.rb:687:in`
>   scss'    main.rb:7:in `block in '

What I am doing wrong?

and here is styles.scss:

```
$red: #903;
$black: #444;
$white: #fff;
$main-font: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

body {
  font-family: $main-font;
}

h1 {
  color: $red;
  font: 32px/1 $main-font;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background: transparent url(/images/logo.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
  padding-left: 84px;
}

@mixin tabs ($background: blue, $color: yellow) {
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: $background;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  li {
    float: left;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 8px;
    background: $background;
    color: $color;
    &:hover {
      background: darken($background, 20%);
    }
  }
}

nav {
  @@include tabs($background: $black, $color: $white);
  font-weight: bold;
}

p {
  font: 13px/1.4 $main-font;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have in your gemfile:

```
gem 'sass'
gem 'sass-rails'
```

If not, add it. Don't forget to run bundle install.

Comment: but it is sinatra not rails, does sass gem require sass-rails gem?

Comment: yes, then manually do gem install 'sass-rails' on the console

Comment: also had to add require 'sass-rails'.

Answer (score 3):

### Perform below steps :

1. Add any of this gem into your gem file `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` or `gem 'sass-rails'`
2. Then install bundle using `bundle` OR `bundle install` command

Answer (score 1):

#### If you are using the asset-pipeline with [sinatra](https://changelog.com/posts/sinatra-asset-pipeline-sprockets-for-sinatra), then this might help. For those using rails this could help.

In my scenario, (running rails 3.2.22.2) on one machine my app worked.
On another machine I cloned the repo and ran into the `uninitialized constant Sass::Engine` error.

#### Moving gem sass-rails did not work for me

I moved `gem 'sass-rails'` out of the `group :assets do` block.
This did not work for me.

#### Solution for me:

`rake assets:clean` removes all compiled assets.

Next time you run `rake rails s`, your assets will be recompiled.
If not, you can run `rake assets:precompile` to compile all your assets.
Or if you are deploying via capistrano, the deploy.rb will run "deploy:assets:precompile" and compile assets for your production/staging machine.

The error seems to occur because sass is not being compiled in the asset pipeline correctly. (Would love to know why this occurs if anyone has the answer)

Comment: I would suggest to run `rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV="development"` to ensure.